# Directory structure when uploading over sftp with Netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans, sftp

When I sync with SVN, my local directory structure looks like this:

```
.../branches/codeigniter/code.php
```

I then need to be able to upload any changes I make over sftp to my webserver for testing before I commit to

```
.../web/code.php
```

I do not want the /branches/codeigniter part of files' path to be preserved. I only want to upload the files in the codeigniter directory to what I specified as the upload directory on the webserver.

However, Netbeans creates a /branches/codeigniter directory on my webserver (since that is what my local directory looks like). So what I get when I upload is:

```
.../web/branches/codeigniter/code.php
```

Is there any way I can tell netbeans to treat the codeigniter directory as the root and do not create any directories on the webserver?

I greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to do what you're asking or not, however you shouldn't have to because you shouldn't be doing it this way :-)

You shoudn't have the entire SVN structure checked out into a project. You checkout each branch you might be working with to a separate project. I think that will solve your problem because then the root of your project is the branch you checked out.